# How to move blobs from App_Data folder of episerver cms site to azure blob storage hosted in azure cloud

Tags: asp.net, blob, azure-blob-storage, azure-cloud-services, episerver

How to move blobs stored in App_Data folder of episerver cms website to azure blob storage, hosted in azure cloud environment?

Comment: Does the `EPiCode.BlobConverter` library provided by Ted Nyberg could help you to solve your issue? If you encounter any issue when using this lib or you could provide more details (e.g. programmatically or manually move your blobs to azure blob storage) about your scenario for us to help you achieve your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [blob converter package on NuGet](https://nuget.episerver.com/en/OtherPages/Package/?packageId=EPiCode.blobconverter) which migrates blobs from disk to another provider, e.g. Azure blob storage.